# Does BufferedInputStream immediately fill up buffer, even before first read operation?

Tags: bufferedinputstream

I am unsure of what is the answer to this question:

If I wrap a BufferedInputStream around an InputStream coming from for example a http call -does the BufferedInputStream automatically and immediately fills up the buffer with data from the InputStream (at "wrapping"-time?), or do I have to call read() on the BufferedInputStream first, before the buffer gets filled up? To put it short: When is the buffer first filled?

I am asking because if I have a http call, I'd like to be able to quickly store the content of small text files in RAM (where they are safer) than relying on the connection to still be up when reading actually starts...

Will I get an IOException with BufferedInputStream if the underlying TCP connection is closed, even if the buffer managed to fill itself up with all data that was actually requested?

Answer (score 1):

When the BufferedInputStream is created, an internal buffer array is created. As bytes from the stream are read or skipped, the internal buffer is refilled as necessary from the contained input stream, many bytes at a time. Until you `read`, it should be empty.

Comment: You are sure of this?

Comment: You could examine it in a debugger. This is my understanding. But I am not exposing myself to liability for your heart monitoring application....

Answer (score 0):

`Fill` method is called only on the first `read` or `skip` method call.

Code extract form BufferInputStream.

```
public synchronized int read() throws IOException {
    if (pos >= count) {
        fill();
        if (pos >= count)
            return -1;
    }
    return getBufIfOpen()[pos++] & 0xff;
}
```

`Skip` too have a similar check for `fill` operation.